# Can't hold down a key with AutoHotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I have a simple script that doesn't seem to behave as expected:

```
^j::
  Send, {Down down}
  Sleep, 10000
  Send, {Down up}
Return
```

I would like it to hold the down arrow key for 10 seconds, and then release.  Instead, it presses the down key once, and breaks the script until reload.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Send` documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Repeating__or_Holding_Down_a_Key) says:

> When a key is held down via the method above, it does not begin auto-repeating like it would if you were physically holding it down (this is because auto-repeat is a driver/hardware feature).

Use [SetKeyDelay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) and specify the number of repetitions:

```
SetKeyDelay, 30
Send {Down 333}
```

`333` is approximately 10000/30

Alternatively you can do it in a `loop` and check for other keys in order to stop sending `Down` key.

Answer (score 1):

Found a nice workaround, try some script like this (adjust the Mynumber variable to your liking and the Sleep aswell)

```
a::
Mynumber = 10
While Mynumber > 0
{
Send {Down DOWN}
Sleep 10
Send {Down UP}
Mynumber--
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation this should work:

```
To hold down or release a key: Enclose in braces the name of the key followed by the word Down or Up. For example:

Send {b down}{b up}
Send {TAB down}{TAB up}
Send {Up down}  ; Press down the up-arrow key.
Sleep 1000  ; Keep it down for one second.
Send {Up up}  ; Release the up-arrow key.
```

docs about holding down keys: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm confused.  I wrote it based on that example, but I can't get it to work properly.

Comment: Where are you trying to implement this or where are you testing it?

Comment: Windows 8.1 running on Bootcamp.  My personal machine.  I might try it on a different machine when I get a chance.